# Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint modest_aryabhata

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm going through [this tutorial](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/)

making docker image with: `docker build -t myapp_back .`

and then want to run container with: `docker run -p 3000:3000 -d myapp_back`

it's simlpe node/express app

But I'm getting an error:

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error
>   response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity
>   on endpoint wizardly_wescoff
>   (a7c53e0d168f915f900e3d67ec72805c2f8e4f5e595f6ae3c7fed8e097886a8b):
>   Error starting userland proxy: mkdir
>   /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:3000:tcp:172.17.0.2:3000: input/output error.

What's wrong?

my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:carbon
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ['npm', 'start']
```

and start in package.json:

```
"start": "nodemon src/app.js --exec babel-node"
```

Answer (score 29):

To solve the following error in Windows: just Restart Docker (from tray menu or selecting the 'Restart Docker...' option in Settings/Reset)

```
Cannot start service YOUR_SERVICE: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ...
```

Answer (score 14):

Looks like it is a known issue from docker: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/573

Try:

1. disabling "Experimental Features" in the Settings/Daemon menu
2. restarting docker
3. stopping all containers.

To stop all containers, run: `docker ps -a -q | ForEach { docker stop $_ }`

> EDIT: Working ShellScript code to **Stop All Containers**

```
for a in `docker ps -a -q`
do
  echo "Stopping container - $a"
  docker stop $a
done
```

Comment: This is the right solution for me.

While my dockerized configuration worked well on OSX, It gave me a similar error on Windows.

In my case, I was using the edge channel release 19.03.0-rc2 for windows with experimental features on

* I turned off port mapping (in command line and then `docker-compose.yml`)  and it worked without the exposed ports.
* Next, I turned off the `experimental features` and the `docker-compose up` worked without any hiccups

Comment: I had a conflict in the ports of the containers, the container I was uploading was trying to use the same port as a container that was running, `3. stopping all containers.` It worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Just restarted my computer and it works now..

Answer (score 4):

I am able to get docker working on my windows 10 pc by resetting docker to the factory defaults. Restarting docker, restarting my machine did not work.

Answer (score 4):

On Mac Mojave, run the following command to find which processes are using the port.

```
sudo lsof -i @localhost:<port_no>
```

In my case I was checking port 8080 so I run

```
sudo lsof -i @localhost:8080
```

I found that the http-alt is running on port 8080 and after getting the process id using above command you can kill the processes by

```
sudo kill -9 <process_id>
```

However, in my case four applications `ArtemisSe, Mail, Google and Slack` are using http-alt on port 8080. Since they look important applications so I changed my port and run the container on 8888 instead of 8080. i.e.

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 <imageid or image name>
```

Comment: docker run failed for container, showing endpoint error. 
Using lsof we could see docker-proxy was still on the ip:port
Killing off that docker-proxy didn't help. A docker restart solved it. 
Conclusion: something went wrong at docker stop/docker rm time, docker-proxy and something else in docker endpoints was left behind.

My error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint containername (1d92a2ef61e35f97aa8d9352ff77a0d378bb73c4b0b8c46a68fdb34812ec7b17): Bind for 10.247.184.31:50000 failed: port is already allocated.
```

Comment: on centos. docker-proxy is part of docker swarm.

Comment: In my case, the problem was application adb android listen in 5037. Restart doesn't work to this. Tks Mian

Answer (score 3):

Restarting the computer is not the actual fix, just a workaround, that one would need to be doing on a frequent basis.

The problem is related with the default windows 10 shutdown behaviour.

The actual fix can be achieved disabling windows fast startup settings:

Control Panel -> Power Options -> Choose what the power button does -> Change settings that are currently unavailable -> Toggle Turn on fast startup

Answer (score 2):

I am running under linux.  If I run docker as root with the sudo command, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just restart docker, right click on its icon then restart. that solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the same error in PHP Container. I solve changing the public port and works.

This command throw error after restart my Windows 10:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name php_apache php_app
```

Solution:

```
docker run -d -p 8081:80 --name php_apache php_app
```

Comment: This isn't a solution but a workaround to make it work isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command to stop your all containers

It worked for me.

for a in `docker ps -a -q`
do
echo "Stopping container - $a"
docker stop $a
done

Answer (score 0):

In some case,restarting your computers solve problem. But it is not really best solution, especially UNIX like operation system.

First of all you should know other process is either running or not in specific port, If you see such port is already in use by other resources. you should kill that procees which running in that port. To do that just follow:

```
  sudo lsof -i @localhost:<port number>
```

Output looks like this

```
Command       PID          USER     TYPE    SIZE  ...

<command>  <pid number>
```

We need pid number which is defines procees id

And then kill that process by its procees id

```
   sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

After kill that procees you can run your new container in such port as you want